# Is it possible to create a stepping power supply switched with transistors?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, fan, series

I am relatively novice with wiring and circuits. I am attempting to power a fan and use transistors to increase the power supply to the fan as I close each transistor!
The base transistor and battery will pass 3 volts to the fan, then when the next transistor is closed (is this the correct term for sending voltage through the transistor when "activating?" the base?), the thought would be it would some how put the battery into series with the other one to provide the fan with 9 volts. I have wired this up at home a few different ways and to no avail.

I will provide further sketch information if requested.

EDIT - I have finally gotten around drawing up the sketch. I am hoping I sketched it correctly. The thought is I use an Arduino to close a transistor, and with the transistor closed current will then flow and power the motor. If it is the right most transistor the thought is it would only be powered by the single, right most power source (each power source is 3 volts). Then if I were to close the first (right most) transistor, and second (middle) transistors it would then supply 6 volts with the two power sources in series to the motor. Then the thought is with the third (left most) transistor closed, and the other two transistors to the right also closed, that the batteries will work in series to provide 9 volts to the motor.

[image: Schematic]

Does this make sense?

Comment: Posting your sketch information would indeed improve the question and may allow people to tell you what exactly you did wrong. With the question as it is you will probably only get some general answers, that your approach is not the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Show a schematic.  Until then, we can't tell what is really being asked.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. I figured one would be needed, wasn't sure though. When I get home I can take a look at my bread board and chalk it up for ya. Sorry!

Comment: @Rev1.0 and Olin Lathrop, I have provided a sketch, I hope this helps clear up any confusion! Thank you!

Comment: No, this won't work as you have sketched it. Q1 and Q2 will short the power sources (batteries?) adjacent to them. I'm sorry but there is so much wrong with this circuit that I can't address it in a comment. If you have an Arduino then the best way to control a d.c. fan is with PWM.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Joe Hass , I realized as I was working on this at home, that I drew the circuit wrong, compared to what I was actually trying. I think I will just delete this post, or close it... I have done some further research and my approach has changed in general. I have discovered also that I may need to consider different types of transistors for what I wish to do among a few other considerations. Baptism by fire! Thank you for your PWM suggestion Joe, I will definitely look into that option as well!

Comment: I have added an answer as I was able to achieve, albeit probably not "best practice" or cleanly, the objectives outlined in my initial question. Thank you so much for all of your relevant insights :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your answer may make intuitive sense but there are some other ways you can get speed control of your electric motor. I've drawn one here as an example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8PShW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am not proficient in circuitlab but you can see I have an [EMF-absorbing diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/motor-drivers-and-kickback-diodes), a motor (I represented this with an inductor), a resistor, and a voltage source.

You will use [PWM](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM) to vary the motor speed. Your voltage source should be equal to or less than your motor's rated voltage. I am unsure of the diode's specifications.

Try to think of the NPN transistor current flow as being from the collector to the emitter. It is not very much like a switch in my opinion. The reason my transistor looks different is because it is in a [Darlington configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) which lets you use less current to turn the transistor on.

Comment: Im going to try this out today! PWM has been mentioned before.  I didn't realize the Arduino supported this. Looks much more elegant! Thank you for the concise and detailed information HL-SDK!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that whatever voltage/current coming from the Arduino output will flow to ground, and not the battery negative, thus I shouldn't worry about providing too much voltage to the motor between the Arduino out and the power source?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the circuit I desired. I ran into some issues along the way, but ultimately this circuit has allowed me to use an Arduino to control how many batteries are in series and are used to power a fan. The Q1, Q2 or Q3 transistor has to be closed, then the Q4 transistor has to be closed and the motor will be spun at a variable speed based on the number of batteries running in series, which is controlled by the Arduino. I want to thank you all for your valuable insights which helped me come to this conclusion. I would very much appreciate further relevant critque and insight to my circuit at hand with the objectives in mind from the posting of the question.

Thanks so much everybody!

[image: Schematic]

Comment: This is the craziest circuit I have seen in a long time. I hope it works for you because it sure has me stumped!

Comment: @HL-SDK haha, I'm a beginning hobbyist and am testing out some different ideas for a project. I expect this to be full on "jerry rigged". The thought is to control the speed of the motor by putting batteries into different series, depending on the transistor I switch on. So for example I switch on the Q3 transistor along with the Q4 transistor, current flows through all three batteries in series, through the motor's positive and out the negative to ground, which is the negative of the left most source in this case. This would supply the most power to the motor. Q2 only two batteries, etc.

Comment: I started as a hobbyist too, and this looks like something that would make sense. Let me suggest another circuit you can use in an answer. It will be different, but should be good for learning.

Comment: Definitely appreciate good input! I just did it this way as well because these are the parts I had on hand, I will be developing further as I go along, I am just doing some conceptual work right now, then when I bring it all together i'm going to try to get everything done as "best" or "correctly" as possible, so i'd love to see your input! Thanks @HL-SDK !

Comment: @HL-SDK This is somewhat analogous to the rail commutation that goes on in a Class G amplifier. Looks reasonable to me.